# Storing non-serializable bean SpringViewDisplayRegistrationBean

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin

I'm playing around with Vaadin and Spring Boot, but at the moment I always see the following log output with every reload:

```
Storing non-serializable bean [com.vaadin.spring.internal.SpringViewDisplayRegistrationBean@561f1569] with name [com.vaadin.spring.internal.SpringViewDisplayRegistrationBean#0] in [UIBeanStore[id=225748b3, name=UI:0]]
```

I don't have any idea where to search, which class or which part of the code could cause that. Any idea where to start?

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems to be a bug. Found this on GitHub. https://github.com/vaadin/framework8-issues/issues/510